# Is there a limit to use the [Header("text")] header?

Tags: unity-game-engine, header, inspector

After finding this useful tool I want to use to organize my scripts. However, when I add the third "category", it gives me the following error:

```
attribute 'Header' is not valid on this decleration type. It is only valid on 'field' declerations.
```

I have tried to use the "order = x" argument, but without succes. Any idea what's going on? I cant seem to find anything about it in the Unity docs.

```
[Header("Feedback settings")]
public string gameName = "";
public string sendToEmail = "";
[Space(5)]
[Header("Canvas settings")]
public Sprite emptyStar, fullStar, button;
[Range(20, 100)]
public float canvasSize;
[Range(-1, 1)]
public float canvasXPosition, canvasYPosition;
public float spritePadding, buttonYOffset;
[Header("Rate settings")] //<-- this one is marked with the above error
public enum MarketPlaces {PC, mobileTablet};
public MarketPlaces compileFor = MarketPlaces.PC;
public string rateLink;
```

**Additional code for Joe Blow**

```
[Header("Canvas settings")]
public Sprite emptyStar, fullStar, button;
[Range(20, 100)]
public float canvasSize;
[Range(-1, 1)]
public float canvasXPosition, canvasYPosition;
public float spritePadding, buttonYOffset;
public enum MarketPlaces { PC, mobileTablet };

[Header("Feedback settings")]
public string gameName = "";
public string sendToEmail = "";

[Header("Rate settings")]
public MarketPlaces compileFor = MarketPlaces.PC;
public string rateLink;

[HideInInspector]
public GameObject currentCanvas, tempButton, subCanvas;

private Button[] starButtons;
private Vector2 canvasPosition;
private GameObject rateMeCanvas, rateButton, contactField, openClient;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Unity have done it, you can't follow it with an enum.

Fortunately, the solution is simple - just move the enum behind it!

```
[Header("Feedback settings")]
public string gameName = "";
public string sendToEmail = "";
[Space(5)]

[Header("Canvas settings")]
// not possible...
// public Sprite emptyStar, fullStar, button;

// you must do this...
public Sprite emptyStar;
public Sprite fullStar;
public Sprite button;

[Range(20, 100)]
public float canvasSize;

[Range(-1, 1)]
public float canvasXPosition, canvasYPosition;
public float spritePadding, buttonYOffset;

public enum MarketPlaces {PC, mobileTablet};
[Header("Rate settings")] // just move to here!
public MarketPlaces compileFor = MarketPlaces.PC;
public string rateLink;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much! This fixed that problem however now I noticed that after I reorganized the variables a bit, I get the "Canvas Settings" header 3 times in the Inspector panel. Is this a something related with the range attributes? *see original post*

Comment: @sdieters I imagine it's more likely to do with how you declared `emptyStar, fullStar, button` all in a single line. The header gets applied to each of the three - if you instead declared one of them first, then the other two on the next line, the header should only appear once (above the first one).